# Is there any way to insert a large value in a mysql DB without changing max_allowed_packet?

Tags: mysql, blob

I know that in order to insert values larger than `max_allowed_packet` bytes into a MySQL database, the default solution would be to assure that both client and server side `max_allowed_packet` variables are bigger than the chunk of data that a query inserts into the DB.

However, is there any way to do so **without** changing the server side variable mentioned above? This would be useful when I have to insert data into a database that is hosted in an ISP that doesn't allow me to change the `max_allowed_packet` limit.

Another related question: MySql `longblob` limit is 4GB, but `max_allowed_packet` limit is 1GB. So, is it possible to insert values larger than 1GB in a `longblob` table column?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I recently stumbled upon this problem. In my case, the server's `max_allowed_packet` was 1 MB and I could do nothing to change it. And I was inserting some data just above 1 MBs. I found two solution candidates.

1) First, using JDBC.
Since *MySQL Connector/J v3.1.9*, there are a few parameters that you could set, here's my set of parameters in the JDBC URL:

Append these:

```
blobSendChunkSize=50000&useServerPrepStmts=true&emulateUnsupportedPstmts=false&maxAllowedPacket=20000000
```

Resulting in JDBC URL:

```
jdbc:mysql://serverip:3306/databasename?noDatetimeStringSync=true&blobSendChunkSize=50000&useServerPrepStmts=true&emulateUnsupportedPstmts=false&maxAllowedPacket=20000000
```

Then you must use `PreparedStatement` to do your inserts, and use the `InputStream` to pass the byte content as a parameter to `setObject`. Note that `setObject` using byte arrays won't enable the blob splitting. The combination of parameters, recent MySQL server (5.0.45 or later), and `InputStream` will send the blob data using `LONG DATA` mechanism, splitting the blob according to `blobSendChunkSize`.

The JDBC solution works and I have tested it.

2) Now, the second candidate, is to use PHP's *mysqli* driver and use `mysqli_send_long_data`. For your convenience, copied from PHP manual example :

```
<?php
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO messages (message) VALUES (?)");
$null = NULL;
$stmt->bind_param("b", $null);
$fp = fopen("messages.txt", "r");
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $stmt->send_long_data(0, fread($fp, 8192));
}
fclose($fp);
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Comment: Just tried mysqli to store a 27mb file on a 1mb max_allowed_packet. Awesome answer, we've been working on a work around for this for almost a week.

Comment: Isn't is possible to set these parameters just for the current transaction/connection? Maybe using `SET ...`? I would prefer this over changing the JDBC URL.

Comment: Worked great when added just these two params useServerPrepStmts=true&maxAllowedPacket=20000000. I saw 'java.sql.SQLException: Parameter of prepared statement which is set through mysql_send_long_data() is longer than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes' which is weird when I used blobSendChunkSize.

Comment: I dont familiar about this but i have same trouble. I want to know for first candidate, how to using `blobSendChunkSize=50000&useServerPrepStmts=true&emulateUnsupportedPstmts=false&maxAllowedPacket=20000000` and how to check result like `jdbc:mysql://serverip:3306/databasename?noDatetimeStringSync=true&blobSendChunkSize=50000&useServerPrepStmts=true&emulateUnsupportedPstmts=false&maxAllowedPacket=20000000`

Comment: help me everyone

Comment: It's *very important to note* that while this solution does not answer the original question: you can't set the client's `maxPacketSize` larger than the server's `max_packet_size`, so the server always wins. I have not been able to get solutions like these to work with MariaDB 10.3 with JDBC. It seems that you simply cannot insert a field value larger than `max_packet_size`.

Comment: Can someone post a working java/jdbc sample? Having no luck, after trying for many many hours.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that there is a way. Maybe splitting the blob will do the trick.

But I think that reading this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/01/1775759.aspx from Reymond Chen is the best answer to your question.

Relational databases are not designed for that kind of use. If you need to store a gigabyte+ blob in a database, well it is better usually to store it on the NFS and just have a short file location string in your DB. Will save you much troubles down the road.

Comment: My second question was more a curiosity, the main question is the first one. I don't intend to put a 3GB blob in a single column... and I don't think my first question is related to violating operating system limits. I mean, it would be useful to put a 2MB blob in a database whose max_allowed_packet is just 1MB, when I cannot change this variable...