# PacketTooBigException when running a sonar analysis

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

When I try and run a sonar analysis I get this exception

> com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large
>   (1807198 > 1048576). You can change this value on the server by
>   setting the max_allowed_packet' variable.

Where on the sonar server should I set this value?

I'm using Sonar 3.4.1 and MySQL 5.x

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Locate the config file `my.cnf` (If your MySQL is running in Windows, locate `my.ini`)

Add this to the config file

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=256M
```

Then, restart mysql

- For Linux, `service mysql restart`
- For Windows

  - `net stop mysql`
  - `net start mysql`

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks for this. Mine was located in /etc/my.cnf. Information is here http://serverfault.com/questions/346647/mysql-wheres-the-my-cnf-path and the magic command to find where it might be is `mysql --help | grep "Default options" -A 1`

Comment: I needed to restart my sonar server for this to eventually work `sudo service sonar restart`

Comment: Restarting the sonar server along with the solution worked for me. Thanks for the tip @AshleyFrieze

Answer (score 6):

I had a same issue however, we had a limitation where **we could not change the MySQL server configuration (max_allowed_packet)**

I was able to get this working by changing the **Client side jdbc URL configurations** -> leaving the server config as is.

```
jdbc:mysql://[dbhost]:[dbport]?useUnicode=true&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useServerPrepStmts=true&maxAllowedPacket=20000000&useSSL=false
```

Check the mysql connector config reference [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

There is one more post on SO that talks abt Client side change in detail - check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754238/is-there-any-way-to-insert-a-large-value-in-a-mysql-db-without-changing-max-allo)

Hope this helps!