# SQL blob data becoming escaped causing max_allowed_packet error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to store binary data as a blob in a MySQL table. I'm aware that my server is configured with a `max_allowed_packet` size of 1M so I'm chunking the data into blobs of 1M. However I still see errors like this:

> Exception: Packet for query is too large (1851203 > 1048576). You can
>   change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet'
>   variable.

What appears to be happening is the `PreparedStatement` is escaping the data in my chunked blob.

e.g. blob `0000` would get sent as `\0\0\0\0`.

So in the worst case data may be doubling in size which causes the error.

My only thought is to chunk the data into half the `max_allowed_packet` size to leave space for potential escape characters.

Is there a better way? Should I pre-escape my data before I chunk it?

Comment: You are using a `setBlob` with an `InputStream`?

Comment: @JoopEggen I am currently using `setBlob(int parameterIndex, Blob x)`

Comment: The data example (0000) would suggest first compressing, but I doubt you can work with that. Blobs are a PITA; think for instance about database backups (and restores).

Comment: I just tried using `setBlob(int parameterIndex, InputStream x)` and got the same error.

Comment: Almost to be expected when the java driver sends full SQL to the database. Nowadays also database engines may keep a _real_ native prepared statement. Most solid seems to store the blobs on the file system as blob-record-id = filename. A pity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to do two things:

1. Use `PreparedStatement#setBlob(int parameterIndex, InputStream x)` instead of `setBlob(int parameterIndex, Blob x)`, as @JoopEggen suggested trying.
2. And set the property `useServerPrepStmts=true` on the `Connection`, as seen over in answer
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/4846674/52176 (other properties were not required in my case).